# ¿Cómo obtener partes de un String en Java?

Tags: java

Necesito obtener partes de un `String` en Java. Sé que con un `split` se puede, pero no logro obtener las partes que necesito.

Esta es mi cadena `57mm x 37mm`.

Necesito los dos numeros, el 57 y el 37

El `57` ya puedo obtenerlo mediante:

```
String[] parts = tama.split("mm");
String to = parts[0];
```

Ahora Necesito el `37`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te sugiero usar en este caso como separador el carácter "x"

```
String tama = "57mm x 37mm";
String[] parts = tama.split("x");
```

usa [.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) para reemplazar "mm" por String vacio y [.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para eliminar los espacios en blanco:

```
String to1 = parts[0].replace("mm","").trim(); //57
String to2 = parts[1].replace("mm","").trim(); //37
```

Otra opción es usando una expresión regular como la sugerida por [@SeanOwen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367418/250260):

```
String tama = "57mm x 37mm";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tama);
    while (m.find()) {
           System.out.println("toc : " + m.group());
    }
```

por ejemplo:

```
String tama = "57mm x 37mm";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); //Define pattern.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tama);

List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    parts.add(matcher.group()); //almacena valores.
}
    //Imprime valores.
   System.out.println("parts : " + parts.get(0) + " , " + parts.get(1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Se puede hacer utilizando una expresión regular que recupere los números presentes en la cadena, así:

```
String str = "57mm x 37mm";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Esto imprimirá un array con los números:

```
[57, 37]
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `Pattern` que recibe una expression regular donde le indicas que esperas numeros:

```
Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher resultados = patron.matcher("57mm x 37mm");

        while (resultados.find()) 
        {
          System.out.println(resultados.group());
        }
```